# Python doctest: how to testing a database insert or delete function?

Tags: python, doctest

The question is simple, the answer I dont know...

I'm newbie with testing and I have problems testing class for drive a sql3 database. What is the best way for test a class like this? Test the class or test the **init** function is not a problem, but the others? the test insert a test row?

```
import sqlite3


class DataBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self._database_path = 'data.sql'
        self._conn = sqlite3.connect(self._database_path)
        self._cursor = self._conn.cursor()

    def get(self, sql):
        # select
        self._cursor.execute(sql)
        dataset = []
        for row in self._cursor:
            dataset.append(row)

        return dataset

   def post(self, sql):
       # insert
       self._cursor.execute(sql)
       self._conn.commit()
```

Thank you for all of you, thank you for all your answers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rollback function of the database.
Just replace `self._conn.commit()` with `self._conn.rollback()` and you can test the validity of your sql with no effects on the data.

If you need to test a series of actions (i.e: get data->modify data->insert new data->remove some data->get data again) you can remove all the `_conn.commit()` in your code, run the tests and finally call `_conn.rollback()`.

Example:

```
import sqlite3


class DataBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self._database_path = 'data.sql'
        self._conn = sqlite3.connect(self._database_path)
        self._cursor = self._conn.cursor()

    def get(self, sql):
        # select
        self._cursor.execute(sql)
        dataset = []
        for row in self._cursor:
            dataset.append(row)

        return dataset

   def post(self, sql):
       # insert
       self._cursor.execute(sql)

   def delete(self, sql):
       # delete
       self._cursor.execute(sql)

   def rollback(self):
       self._conn.rollback()

# You do your tests:
db = DataBase()
data = db.get('select name from table')
new_data = ['new' + name for name in data]
db.post('insert into table values {}'.format(','.join('({})'.format(d) for d in new_data)))
db.delete('delete from table where name = \'newMario\'')
check = bool(db.get('select name from table where name = \'newMario\''))
if check:
  print('delete ok')

# You make everything as before the test:
db.rollback()
```

Comment: Thank you very match for your answer but: what if I must do it with DocTest? It's possible run extense code in DocTest??

Answer (score 0):

I think the `CursorTests` in official sqlite3 tests is a good example.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/sqlite3/test/dbapi.py#L187

You can write `setUp` and `tearDown` methods to set up and rollback the database.

```
from unittest import TestCase


class TestDataBase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.db = DataBase()

    def test_get(self):
        pass # your code here

    def test_post(self):
        pass # your code here
```

Comment: Thank you very match for your answer but: what if I must do it with DocTest? It's possible??